# Strange ASP.Net Error: .net 4.6.1, VS2015 - interpolated strings not supported?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.6

Strange ASP.Net Error (WebForms): `.net 4.6.1, VS2015`

> Error  BC36716 Visual Basic 12.0 does not support interpolated strings.

No clue why i'm getting this. Why is it reporting VB 12.0 under VS2015?

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="true" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at the last answer at
http://forums.asp.net/t/2061764.aspx?VS2015+claims+it+does+not+support+interpolated+strings

> Found the answer here if anyone else has the same problem. It looks
>   like the Roslyn compiler for Web Site project types is not icluded
>   with VS2015 and must be downloaded separately.  See:
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/05/12/enabling-the-net-compiler-platform-roslyn-in-asp-net-applications.aspx

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, since links die or change over time. Instructions from those sites should be copied into this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything! Until this worked. I removed two packages I had installed from NuGet. Both of them where from Microsoft, one was a Roslyn package and the other was a compiler. When I took those out of my project all my errors about interpolated strings went away. I am running Visual Studio 2017.

So look through your packages and remove ones you do not need (maybe leftover from an old setup like I had)...

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: You forgot to mention the packages to be removed.