# VB.NET is not allowing string interpolation in aspx files

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

If I do string interpolation like so:

```
Dim answer as integer = 42
Dim fred as string = $"the answer is {answer}"
```

It works if I do it in a VB file, but if I do it in an ASPX file, I get this error:

> BC30037: Character is not valid.

How do I enable string interpolation in ASPX files?

Comment: You did not specify the VS version (or any other). Maybe this applies: [Strange ASP.Net Error: .net 4.6.1, VS2015 - interpolated strings not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35127022/7444103)

Comment: The Visual Studio version is 2019. I'm getting a different error from that other question, so I'm not sure if it's the same issue.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548699/how-to-use-c-sharp-6-with-web-site-project-type

Comment: I can't even use LINQ; if I add an import statement at the top of the page e.g. `<%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" %>` I still get compile errors on LINQ methods...